# Open a file, by looking in an ordered list of directories (search path)

Tags: python, file-system

I have a small Python application that needs to load a few different files (templates and config files). It should look in a number of destinations, in the following order, and load the file from the first destination that contains such a file.

- current working directory
- `$MYAPP_PATH` (may contain several paths,separated by colon)
- `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/myapp/resources/`

I have written the following:

```
def open_sp(filepath): #open searchpath
    pathlist = []
    pathlist.append('.')
    pathlist.extend(os.environ['MYAPP_PATH'].split(':'))
    pathlist.append(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)),'resources'))
    for p in pathlist:
        try:
            return open(os.path.join(p,filepath))
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass
    raise FileNotFoundError()
```

And I have exported the following environment variable in shell:

```
$ export MYAPP_PATH=/home/jdoe/templates/:/home/jdoe/legacy_templates/
```

In my case, it will look for the file in the following locations:

- `./foo.conf`
- `/home/jdoe/templates/foo.conf`
- `/home/jdoe/legacy_templates/foo.conf`
- `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/foo.conf`

And it seems to work. But I suspect this could be much more elegant, perhaps by using some built-in Python tool, maybe from the `importlib`-package.

Also, if considering my code, I'm not sure if FileNotFound is the proper exception to throw, since it expects a path argument, and I am not sure which of the path arguments to provide.

Comment: A colon ':' can be a valid character in a Windows path. It might make your code more portable to use a semi-colon ';' to separate paths in `MYAPP_PATH`.

Comment: @RootTwo: Good point. However I believe the convention on Unix is to use colons as separator, and I simply chose to stick to this convention.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than incrementally building up a list, you can just use a tuple literal.

Add PEP484 type hints.

Prefer `pathlib` over `os.path` for path manipulation.

This function shouldn't be obligated with opening the file, only finding the first matching path.

Raising `FileNotFoundError` is fine but you should give it a sane error message string.

### Suggested

```
import os
from pathlib import Path


def get_path(filename: str) -> Path:
    paths = (
        '.',
        *os.environ['MYAPP_PATH'].split(':'),
        Path(__file__).parent / 'resources',
    )
    for p in paths:
        path = Path(p) / filename
        if path.is_file():
            return path

    raise FileNotFoundError(f'{filename} not found in the search directories')
```